# Autopopulating a Mysql Table from Another Mysql Table with iterations through PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

The explanation of this may seem a bit long and convoluted but please bear with me. In essence what I want to do is fill a mysql table(A) from another mysql table(B) in my database but in order to do so I need to duplicate values in table (A) so that there will be enough entries to accomodate for the values in table B.

Now for a more concrete example

How the tables look

#### course_details table

```
 course_details_id | course_id |  year_id  | teacher_id
+------------------+-----------+-----------+------------+
        1               1       To be Set       36
        2               2       To be Set       54
        3               3       To be Set       78
        4               4       To be Set       23
```

#### year table

```
 year_semester_id | year | semester
+-----------------+------+---------+
         1          2012      1
         2          2012      2
         3          2012      3
         4          2012      4
         5          2013      1
         6          2013      2
         7          2013      3
         8          2013      4
```

How I want the table to look

```
 course_details_id | course_id | year_id | teacher_id
-------------------+-----------+---------+------------+
         1               1          1          36
         2               1          2          36
         3               1          3          36
         4               1          4          36
         5               1          5          36
         6               1          6          58
         7               1          7          36 
         8               1          8          47
         9               2          1          54
        10               2          2          54
        11               2          3          54
        12               2          4          67
        13               2          5          67
        14               2          6          54
        15               2          7          54
        16               2          8          54
```

How the code looks

```
<?php
require_once('open_db.php');
get_dbhandle();

$query_year = "SELECT * FROM year"; 
$result_year = mysql_query($query_year) or die(mysql_error());
$num_year_rows = mysql_num_rows($result_year);
$num_year_rows = ($num_year_rows - 1);

$query_yearid = "SELECT year_semester_id FROM year"; 
$result_yearid = mysql_query($query_yearid) or die(mysql_error());

$result_ccheck = mysql_query("SELECT course_id FROM courses");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_ccheck))
    {
      $course_id = $row['course_id'];
               
       for($i = $num_year_rows; $i >= 0; $i--)
       {
        $query_cdetails = "INSERT INTO course_details (course_id) VALUES ('$course_id')";
        $result_cdetails = mysql_query($query_cdetails);
                       
           while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_yearid))
           {
             $year_semester_id = $row['year_semester_id'];
             $query = "INSERT INTO course_details(year_semester_id) SELECT year_semester_id FROM year";
             $result = mysql_query($query);
            }
                                               
        }      
    }
?>
```

What it does vs what I want it to do: As it currently is set, it correctly creates duplicates of each course_id in course_details table to match the number of year_semester_id's which exist in the years table which is perfect. The problem comes to inserting the year_semester_id's in each corresponding table slot of the table course_details.

In other words, to ensure that when course_id =1 , year_semester_id=1, course_id=1, year_semester_id =2,....course_id=1, year_semester_id=8, course_id=2, year_semester_id=1,  course_id=2, year_semester_id=2......course_id=2, year semester_id =8, course_id=3, year_semester_id =1 etc and so on.... Therein lies the issue.

A recap of how the code works, it counts the number of year_semester_id's in the years table, it then subtracts that number by 1 which is the amount of times the course_id is currently in the course_details table and it duplicates it by that number. This total number (the duplicates) plus the original course_id should be the total amount of year_semester_ids. I now want to insert every year_semester_id for every course_id that exists and loop through until each course_id is accounted for. Thank you

Comment: please try to use the [code formatting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and [read](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title)

Comment: Data in table 1 doesn't fit in the table structure.

Comment: The data in Table 1 was just the vital information which was to be used in the code itself. The teacher_id for now is supplementary and not important nor will it be filled out. But the template is there for future additions. The year_id is currently not set as it is to be filled in from the year_semester_id table so in the course_details table the values are currently empty.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: Just to clarify none of this code will be used by users at any point, this is simply to populate the table on my own without having to manually type in all the entries which would be nearly impossible. My knowledge of PDO is severely limited and for mysqli it would just be a simple matter of replacing the mysql functions with mysqli.

Comment: If you make a relation table, it would be easier to do that, make a table with 2 foreign keys, 1 pointing to course_details_id and the other pointing to year_semester_id, that way you can make a query to insert into that table every years for each course. When you want to get the final table, you can use the INNER JOIN to join the relation between tables, and make a selection of both tables.

Comment: Hmm Ricardo doesn't that create unnecessary convolution, in other words extra tables for no reason if a one-time script can perform the same duty? Currently the course_details table has every column set as foreign keys besides the course_details_id which is the primary key.

Comment: ok 2 things pop up when i look at your code: 1. you are using the same variable name ($row) in a nested while loop, this means you are overwriting data while still proccessing it. 2. your insert query has a select in it with no where cluase meaning it will always insert the same value

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like what you're attempting to do could easily be done without bloating your database by taking advantage of relational tables. In this case, if I'm understanding you correctly, the end result here is you want to have duplicates of all the rows from `course_details` with the empty column set to each of the rows from the `year` table.

That being true, you could select that data using JOIN statements:

```
SELECT `a`.`course_id` , `b`.`year_semester_id` as `year_id` , `a`.`teacher_id` FROM `course_details` `a` INNER JOIN `year` `b`
```

That should return the data you want in a MySQL resultset. If you want to insert that data into a table, just make sure the table has the correct columns, and set the `course_Details_id` field to auto increment and do:

```
INSERT INTO `tablename` ( `course_id` , `year_semester_id` , `year_id` ) VALUES (
    SELECT `a`.`course_details_id` , `a`.`course_id` , `b`.`year_semester_id` as `year_id` , `a`.`teacher_id` FROM `course_details` `a` INNER JOIN `year` `b`
)
```

This should insert all the data you need into the new MySQL table without the need for PHP scripts.

Comment: Actually looking over this answer Brian, I tested it out and saw it also duplicated course_details_id which makes the innerjoin meaningless as multiple rows would have the same course_details_d and course_id making it difficult to differentiate them.

Comment: Ah right you are. I've updated the queries to exclude that field. In the select statement you don't really need it if you're just reading the data from the database this way. Alternatively you could select the key fields from the tables yourself if you need them. The insert was updated as well and should be used with an auto_increment field as the key for the table.

Answer (score 0):

[This is what im talking about](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ebcc3/1) check the code  iy you have a trouble understanding, let me know.

Comment: Thank you very much. I currently already had made a courses table with differing information but adding the changes you have will even make the relational database even more modular. Extremely appreciate it.

Comment: Definitely an answer to the question. When I have enough rep I will give the the upvote to you both guaranteed.